Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH ERROR
So I am trying to run a few examples from this GITHUB repo in Google Colab: https://github.com/monk1337/resp/blob/main/README.md
And, whenever I try to use:
cp = connected_papers()

papers = cp.download_papers(paper_names[0], n=1)

print(papers)

I get an error as shown below:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     79         except OSError as err:
     80             if err.errno == errno.ENOENT:
---> 81                 raise WebDriverException(
     82                     "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
     83                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
What should I do? I have broken my head tryging various methods to overcome this, can someone guide me as to what should be done?
Other methods seem to run just fine, however connected papers seems to give this chromedriver issue which I have tried to resolve without success
